# Google Firestore - Deploy Error: Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to deploy my functions to firebase, I'm getting the following error:

Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?

```
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. (/user_code/index.js:6:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Firebase:

> "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1"
>
> "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1"

This issue is already raised here : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/515 (But for 'firebase-admin' module)

Based on inputs from there, I tried doing this:
npm install --save-exact firebase-functions@0.7.0 npm install --save-exact firebase-admin@5.4.0.
but I ran into the following error :

*Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. Please ensure you have the latest firebase-functions SDK by running "npm i --save firebase-functions@latest" inside your functions folder.*

> Node version, v8.4.0.

Index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); 
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); 
var express = require('express'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

const users = require('../functions/controllers/users.controller'); 
var app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.post('/users', users.createUsers); 
exports.myappusers = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

users.controller.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.createUsers = function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.name){
        return res.status(404).send({message: 'User name cannot be empty'})
    }
    else{
        db.collection('user-test')
        .add({
            name: req.body.name
        })
        .then((writeResult) => {
            return res.json({ result: `User ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this `npm i --save firebase-functions@latest`?

Comment: Please show the minimal code from your index.js that reproduces this error.

Comment: @PeterHaddad, yes I did. I get back the first error about express. Kind of, stuck in a cycle.

Comment: FYI, just checked the node_modules folder, _express_ exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After breaking my head for a day, I did the obvious. I installed Express and did a deploy but this time I got the same error for body-parser, `_Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'_`
Installed body-parser as well. Deployed again, *voila!! deployment was successful.*

But I'm not really sure why I had to explicitly install them even though both `express` and `body-parser` module were present in the `node-modules` folder.

Summary:

```
npm install --save --save-exact express@4.16.2    
npm install --save --save-exact body-parser@1.18.2    
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Answer (score 2):

first use

npm install --save firebase

in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\functions>

remember install firebase should be in functions folder the it will work properly

you should see this dependencies

"dependencies": {
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see express in the node_modules folder but still get the error is because it is not added in the package.json. Add it in the package.json in dependencies like this:

```
"dependencies":{
   "express": "4.16.3",
   "firebase-admin": "5.13.0",
   "firebase-functions": "2.0.2"
 }
```

You should be able to deploy now.